# How can you read a gridview cell when editing besides textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I having a little dilemma and Im not sure how to work around this issue. If I am editing a gridview, I am reading the rows as such

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@X", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[15].Controls[0]).Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Y", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[15].Controls[0]).Text;
```

When the gridview is in edit mode, both cells X and Y have textboxes because that is the default edit mode. I created the columns manually and I would like for cell X to be "read only". How can I change the code so that I can read the cell X without a textbox?  Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Can you clarify your intentions around X and Y, and what does edit mode have to do with anything?

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda struggling to understand the problem. It would simplify your request for the textbox if you just used GridView.FindControl("lblMyLabel"). If you did that you wouldn't need to even look for the text box, just search for the label in the ViewMode rather than the text box in the Edit Mode

Comment: Yes mikey that is exactly what Im wanting to do. How could I create such a label for the gridview?

Comment: Hold on, I'm trying to write out a full answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit too simple, but how about:

```
    var lblHolder = (Label) GridView1.FindControl("lblMyLabel")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@X", SqlDbType.Char).Value = lblHolder.Text
```

Just search for your label (or whatever is holding your value) directly

Then your Grid View can look something like this

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server"                         AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="95%" Font-Names="Verdana">
                    <RowStyle Height="40px" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col1">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMyLabel" runat="server" 
                                     Text='<%# eval("MyDataBaseField")%>' />
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Then you just need to connect a data source to the grid. There are of course loads of other ways to do it, but searching for controls by their Ids is a lot easier than trying to figure out their number in an array

Comment: So I would have to convert that column into a templatefield and add a label basically?

Comment: The label was just a way to store the data when it's in view mode, you can use any control you want. Then search for it and grab its value